# Toggling opacity of divs when clicking on another div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a div toggle the opacity of multiple other divs on click.
If anyone could point me in the right direction as to where I'm going wrong here, that would be great :)

```
function toggle_opacity(className) {
   var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
   if(x.style.opacity == '0')
      x.style.opacity = '1';
   else
      x.style.opacity = '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will return an array, so wrap your code in a loop:

```
function toggle_opacity(className) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if(x[i].style.opacity == '0')
          x[i].style.opacity = '1';
        else
          x[i].style.opacity = '0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sploicers/59mL6/) has 3 problems.

1) `document.getElementsByClassName(className)` returns an array, so you need to select the first element:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
```

2) Your `if` needs to check if the opacity is `0`, not `'0'`.

3) Your JS needs to be in `<head>`, not `onLoad`.

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59mL6/12/).

Answer (score 0):

Have updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59mL6/11/) with the changes:

I have changed the function to match your requirement.

```
e1[0].style.opacity = '1';
e1[1].style.opacity = '0';
```

Added these 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

may be you want this 
I done with jquery

html--

```
<div id="div_1" class="ope">
</div>
<div id="div_2" class="ope">
</div>
<div id="div_3" class="ope">
</div>
```

css---

```
.ope{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jquery--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ope").click(function(){
        var thisdiv = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert(thisdiv);
         $(".ope").css('opacity','1');
        $("#"+thisdiv).css('opacity','0.5');

    })
})
```